# Unable to install npm package from github from package.json on heroku

Tags: node.js, github, npm-install, package.json

I am using a package from github which is to be install from package.json file. But when I deploy the app on heroku, It is not able to install the package.

In package.json, I tried using different methods as below,

"sqlike": "git+https://username:access-token@github.com/vijjuu/SQLike.git"

"sqlike": "https://github.com/vijju/SQLike#master"

"sqlike": "https://github.com/vijjuu/SQLike/tarball/master"

"sqlike": "vijjuu/SQLike"

Error: Cannot find module 'SQLike'
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223971+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223973+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223975+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223976+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223977+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/server.js:2:18)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223979+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223980+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223982+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223983+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-06-14T18:26:48.223985+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

Answer (score -1):

1) Your exporting your sql like but not importing it anywhere.
2) You don't have a server like ( node ) to run it on Heroku.

Comment: Sorry rock-star, I didn't get your point. Please can you elaborate a liittle more.

Comment: I am trying to say that.
You can't push this code to heroku since you don't have any kind of server running.